# Google +1 button doesn't show up on iPad

Tags: ipad, mobile, google-plus-one

I've integrated the Google **+1** button into my site ([link](http://carsabi.com)), but for the life of me can't get it to show up on my iPad. It works fine in FF and Chrome on my desktop, and their FAQ claims that they support mobile browsers ([link](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1140194)).

Anyone had experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to fix this. Just remove the `annotation="inline"` attribute from the +1 button.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is currently no fix or workaround.

I have not seen a working google plus one button on the iPad. Even Google's +1 buttons are not working:
http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/

Comment: Actually it is possible, see my answer below